# Sending FormData via POST across domains

Tags: iis, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have a javascript file that sends a FormData variable to another site as follows:

```
xhr.open("post", "http://host/path/file.php", true);
xhr.send(data);
```

The data variable is correctly populated I have verified that this is not the issue as the payload on my Network tab reads the correct values, the request header has a content-length > 0 :

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:6021726
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAj8A2cYqFIFtNwHI
Host:host
Origin:http://host
Referer:http://host/path
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36
```

However the response header content-length=0:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 02 Oct 2014 19:34:49 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I read there is an issue with IE and Windows Authentication that causes this but I am using Chrome and Firefox.  For both sites I have allowed both Anonymous and Windows Authentication (they are both IIS sites).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As an additional comment, I've read some people having similar issues saying when they switch to GET rather than POST it works.  That is not the case for me, my content length is still 0 when I send the data via GET.

Comment: I feel like the code is fine, the request contains data, but it never arrives at the PHP script with data.  Somewhere in between it gets dropped, I am thinking it likely has to do with my IIS server but I don't know why it is blocking it or how to fix the issue.

Comment: new update, I am able to get value from my POST variable now I played around with so many things over the past few days I am not sure what did it but part of my data comes through.  My post array contains 3 strings and one media file.  What I am testing with is a 5MB video and it does not come through.  I get no error, but when I print the POST array it is not part of the array and only a small portion of the data sent is received (according to the content length "340 received" of "6021739 sent") please help.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it but the Content-Type of my request is "multipart/form-data" but the response header Content-Type is "text/html" could this be the issue?  If so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was pointless posting my problem here as no one helped, in the case the some else has this issue   I will post what fixed my issue.  It seems when you send an XMLHttpRequest of type multipart/form-data that string data can be found in the $_POST variable but any file data is located in the $_FILES variable.

Also I was confused in what the browser was telling me, it wasn't necessarily that data wasn't being sent but the Content-Length of my response header was empty until I actually printed the POST/FILES variables then it was showing a length > 0. I was stuck on that for a while so I thought I would also add it to my solution.